# Why is the pseudoinverse of an orthogonal projection matrix itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices, pseudoinverse

From both [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F027836498700600201) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Properties), it is mentioned that for an orthogonal projection matrix $(I - A^+A)$ its pseudo inverse is itself, i.e., $$(I - A^+A)^+ = I - A^+A$$ Why is this the case? Can someone please help me understand how this can be proved?

Comment: a fast way to prove it is through the SVD of the matrices, do you know it?

Comment: You know that $A^+$ satisfies the four [Penrose conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition). Use this to show that for the projector $P=(I-A^+A),\,$ the ansatz $P^+=P\,$ satisfies each of the Penrose conditions and therefore $P$ is its own pseudoinverse.

Comment: @greg that makes sense!

Comment: @Exodd Is possible to elaborate on the proof?

Comment: @QualsYet2Pass There's a way to compute the pseudoinverse through the SVD, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Singular_value_decomposition_(SVD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few months I think I am able to answer my own question, as @greg said the key is to use the four Penrose conditions:

> Consider a real linear operator $A: \mathbf{X}\rightarrow\mathbf{Y}$. A real linear operator $M: \mathbf{Y}\rightarrow\mathbf{X}$ is the unique pseudo-inverse of $A$, denoted as $M = A^\dagger$ if and only if it satisfies the four Moore-Penrose conditions:
> \begin{equation*}
>     \mathrm{(i)}\ (AM)^T = AM,\ \ \mathrm{(ii)}\ (MA)^T = MA,\ \ \mathrm{(iii)}\ AMA = A,\ \ \mathrm{(iv)}\ MAM = M
> \end{equation*}

Then if we see $A$ as $(I - A^\dagger A)$ and $M$ also as $(I - A^\dagger A)$ we can check whether they satisfy the above four conditions.

First, we need show that $(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}) = (I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})$, this can be shown via direct calculation

\begin{align*}
    (I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}) &= I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}\\
    &= I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}\\
    &= I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}.
\end{align*}

Then we can have
\begin{align}
(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}))^T &= (I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})^T = I^T - (\mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})^T = I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}\\
((I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}))^T &= I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}\\
(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}) &= I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}\\
(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}) &= I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A}
\end{align}

Thus, we show that $(I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})^\dagger = (I - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{A})$.

Answer (score 1):

When thinking about the pseudoinverse, I often find that the most illuminating viewpoint is to start with the geometric definition of the pseudoinverse of a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$.

The pseudoinverse of $A$ takes as input a vector $b \in \mathbb R^n$ and returns as output the vector $x$ of least norm which satisfies $Ax = \tilde b$, where $\tilde b$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $R(A)$.

Suppose $P \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a matrix that performs orthogonal projection onto a subspace $W$. Let $b \in \mathbb R^n$. The pseudoinverse of $P$ maps $b$ to the least norm solution of $Px = \tilde b$, where $\tilde b$ is the projection of $b$ onto $R(P) = W$.

But what is the vector of least norm whose projection onto $W$ is $\tilde b$? It is the vector $\tilde b$ itself, of course. In other words, the least norm solution to $Px = \tilde b$ is $x = \tilde b = Pb$.

Therefore, the pseudoinverse of $P$ maps $b$ to $Pb$. This shows that the pseudoinverse of $P$ is $P$.